# How to replace barcodes with descriptions from a list using javascript?

Tags: javascript

We have a webpage used for scanning inventory. We use our own custom barcodes for checking things in and out. These are in sequential order such as 0000024, 0000025, 0000026, etc. Each of these barcodes has a corresponding description of the item to go with it. I was wondering if there is a way that when scanning the barcode into the webpage it can substitute the barcode number with the item description automatically. I am playing around with string replacement but am unsure how to do this for lists of items.

Comment: What is your desired input, desired output, and question?

Comment: Where's the description stored?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  What have you done so far?  Where are you stuck?  What do you need help with?  Without seeing your project there's not much we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an object and then search for the barcode in it.

```
var barcodes = {
  "000555":"This is a discription for 000555",
  "000666":"This is a discription for 000666"
}
```

Then when the value of the input changes look it up and then put it in the p element.

```
$("input[type=text]").on("input", function(){ //on value changed
    this.value //text in the textbox
    $("p").text(barcodes[this.value]); //find the value of the text box in the barcodes object
});
```

[Here is a Fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/XGeXT/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object literal which maps barcodes to their description:

```
var barCodeMap = {
        "0000024": "description 24", 
        "0000025": "description 25",
        "0000026": "description 26"
    },
    scannedBarCode = "0000025",
    descriptionOfScannedBarCode = barCodeMap[scannedBarCode];

console.clear();
console.log(descriptionOfScannedBarCode);
```

(The website could download the map from the server in [JSON format](http://www.json.org/), using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The downloaded JSON string can be converted to a JavaScript object by calling [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).)